# Get Android GPS coordinates

Tags: android, gps, adb, android-sdk-tools, android-gps

I want to read Coordinates from my Huawei P30 via ADB.

ADB call: adb shell dumpsys location

Problem: 
Output is like:

> ```
> Last Known Locations:
> gps: Location[gps 11******,14******
> ```

So, it is censored with stars... GPS is turned on, any idea?

Comment: I don't think there's another way than yours. The Android OS seems to protect the location data from being extracted...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know any setting to disable that "protection"? I get the exact coordinates via apps, but can not read them out via adb...

Comment: I don't know. But if you explain what the end-goal here is there might be a better solution to the problem